# How can i show input boxes when the array values are empty or length === 0 in my template?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am showing the values base on user enters in inputbox So it is in format of array of arrays I mean array inside arrays for example(['str',[]] So I am looping in my component.html file and render data in input box So my issue is if array values are empty So i need to show empty input box which is not happening my case How can i keep a check so that if value is empty also I can show input box

```
            <div class="row">
              <span class="col-2 align-self-center firstletter">{{ a[0] }}</span>
              <div class="col-4"><label for="startTime">Start Time
                  <span class="red-star">*</span>
                </label></div>
              <div class="col-4"><label for="endTime">End Time
                  <span class="red-star">*</span>
                </label></div>
            </div>
              <div class ="test" *ngIf="a[1].length == 0">
                <p>No opening hours</p>
              </div>
            <div class="row" *ngFor="let m of a[1]; let j = index">
                <span class="col-2 align-self-center"></span>
              <div class="col-4">
                <input type="text" name="startTime" 
                  class="form-control cust-input-class form-control-sm mt-1 col-10 d-inline" [value]="m[0] === undefined ? '': m[0] "
                  (change)="onStartChangeValue($event.target.value,m, m[0])" /> 
                <!-- [ngModel]="m?.startTime" -->
              </div>
              <div class="col-4">
                <input type="text" name="endTime"
                  class="form-control cust-input-class form-control-sm mt-1 col-10 d-inline" [value]="m[1] ===  undefined ? '':m[1]"
                  (change)="onEndChangeValue($event.target.value,m, m[1])" />
                <!-- [ngModel]= "m?.endTime" (ngModelChange)="m.endTime = $event"  -->
              </div>
              <div class="col-2 align-self-center" *ngIf="j == 0">
                <span class="add-item-icon" (click)="o2editaddTime(k)"></span>
              </div>
              <div class="col-2 align-self-center" *ngIf="j > 0">
                <span class="remove-item-icon" (click)="o2editremoveTime(k, j)"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- </div> -->
          </div>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the two input box with opposite condition

```
<input type="text" name="hey" *ngIf="array.array">{{ Any thing }}
<input type="text" name="hey" *ngIf="!array.arrayy" >
```